# setting cookies for my website using anyone's website

Tags: cookies

Assume two domain **abc.com** and **xyz.com**. And my domain is **mydomain.com**. When user visit any web page from **abc.com** or **xyz.com** an ajax request is send from that page to my web server and i return some html as response. At that moment i want to set cookies for me(**mydomain.com** not for **abc.com** or **xyz.com**) to user's browser.

Assume user visit **abc.com** and i set some cookies for **mydomain.com** not **abc.com**. After that when user want to visit **xyz.com** and at that time **xyz.com** send an ajax request to **mydomain.com** for a html response at that moment i want to identify the user if he is a new user or a returning user already visited **abc.com** or **xyz.com** . When i set cookies, i give user an userId as cookies that is stored in user's computer. And through this userId i want to identify the user.

Is this possible to set cookies for **mydomain.com** not **abc.com** in user's computer through an ajax response remembering user is visiting **abc.com** not **mydomain.com**?
If possible then what is the way?

And i also want to set flash cookies because i don't want to consider a returning user as a new user.
I will save the userId in my Database. 
Above all these i also want to know the **geolocation** of the user i.e. latitude, longitude, country, zip, region etc.

Besides that i also want to count how many times the user visited **abc.com** or **xyz.com** and his/her location. 
**mydomain.com**, **abc.com** and **xyz.com** are completely different domains. There is no relation between these three domains.
There may be **infinite** **abc.com** or **xyz.com** and **infinite user**.

How this can be possible?
Is this a legal one?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into JWT. https://jwt.io/

That would be a good way to handle sessions and share user details.

Also the first time when you set the cookie to your domain and if the user keeps returning to your website in the same browser ( can be different tabs), he should continue to have the cookie available and you should still be able to read the token from the requests from the browser for your service.

Comment: my question is that how can i set cookie?